# App crashes with Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON

Tags: java, android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I am new to the broadcast receiver and implemented broadcast receiver dynamically as shown below

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    BroadcastReceiver mService=new StarterOnBoot();
    registerReceiver(mService,filter);
```

in manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.example.autostartter">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AutoStartTer">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AutoStartTer.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".RuntimePermission"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AutoStartTer.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I have also created a button, by clicking who send broadcast manually as shown below

```
view.findViewById(R.id.button_second).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
            MainActivity.instance_main.sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    });
```

Broadcast Service is

```
package com.example.autostartter;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.logging.Handler;

public class StarterOnBoot extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Broadcast Hit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME))
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_UNLOCKED))
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON))
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT))
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
}
```

the broadcast works properly when the user unlocks the screen. However, when I click on the button the application crashes with the following exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.autostartter, PID: 30645
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON from pid=30645, uid=10245
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2074)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2042)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1990)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.broadcastIntent(IActivityManager.java:5089)
    at android.app.ContextImpl.sendBroadcast(ContextImpl.java:1059)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:458)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:458)
    at com.example.autostartter.FirstFragment$2.onClick(FirstFragment.java:44)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7185)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7162)
    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:819)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27684)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
 Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:15351)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:15202)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:15991)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:2051)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2799)
```

I have also acquired overlay permissions

Please ignore any mistake not directly related to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission to the Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: It does not resolve the issue. Still receiving the same exception.

Comment: Provide your Manifest and the StarterOnBoot method definition.

Comment: ok I have edited my code. Please have a look at the problem again.

Comment: Register your broadcast receiver in the Manifest file.

Comment: added but still the same exception

Comment: @AmitBhatiwal Any luck how you fixed this exception?